# How to add target platform into VS 2010

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, windows-xp

I run VS 2010 Express on WinXP. I got .net 4.0 framework SDK and .net 2.0 sdk intalled in my system. Problem is that i am not able to choose .net 2.0 as a target platform for my application - only .net 4.0 is available. Is there and way to add 2.0 as a target platform for .net applications?

Comment: Which version of VS2010 are you using, and what kind of project are you creating?

Comment: This link contains all the info you need: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398197(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: I open dialog where i chooe target platform - and i have only 4.0 as a choice.

Comment: If .Net 2.0 is installed on the system, but is not visible as an option, there is probably something wrong with the installation. It would be best to uninstall and reinstall.

Comment: I would really suggest installing the [.net 3.5 sdk](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3138), it will give you the options for 2.0, 3.0 and 3.5

Comment: I will delete 2.0 installation, than make a try with 3.5 sdk. After that i will write here about results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing .Net 3.5 Framework fixed the problem.